# Question regarding a proof of Riemann's theorem concerning removable singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently going through the theorem and there is a part in the proof that throws me for a loop.


$\textbf{If we have a function $f(z)\in\mathcal{H}(B'(a,r))$ which is bounded on $B'(a,r)$, then $f(z)$ has a}$

$\textbf{removable singularity in $a$.}$

Define $h(a)=0$ and $h(z)=(z-a)^2f(z)$. We then see it follows that $h'(a)=\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{h(z)-h(a)}{z-a}=\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^2f(z)=0$ because of the boundedness of $f$. $\texttt{The proof then continues with the claim that $h(z)=(z-a)^2g(z)$ for a suitable}$

$g(z)\in\mathcal{H(B(a,r)}$.

My question then is, why is it $(z-a)^2$? How have we proven that the order of $h$ in $a$ is 2? I get that you can expand it with power series because it is holomorphic, ie. $h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$. But let's say $a_2=0$, then $h''(a)=0$ and the order is not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ with $h(0) = a_0 = 0$ and $h'(0) = a_1 = 0$, so
$$
h(z)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n = (z-a)^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}(z-a)^n = (z-a)^2 g(z)
$$
where $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}(z-a)^n$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=a$.

The multiplicity of the zero of $h$ at $z=a$ is *at least* two. It can be higher, but that does not invalidate the conclusion.

What you are perhaps thinking of is this: $h$ has a zero of multiplicity $p \ge 2$, so
$$
 h(z) = (z-a)^p \phi(z)
$$
where $\phi$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=a$ with $\phi(a) \ne 0$. But then
$$
 h(z) = (z-a)^2 \underbrace{(z-a)^{p-2} \phi(z)}_{g(z)}
$$
is the desired representation.

Comment: Ah, we're just allowing g(z) going to zero when goes towards a. I had convinced myself that would be wrong. I see now that it isn't. Thank you!